# traefik returns 404 for unconditional forward to a backend

Tags: traefik

I want to unconditionally forward all requests to a backend, but when I try to visit it, I keep getting 404. Here are my configs.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  load-balancer:
    image: traefik:1.5-alpine
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./traefik:/etc/traefik
  server1:
    build: server1
    ports:
      - 8081:80
```

traefik.toml

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http"]
debug = true
logLevel = "DEBUG"
[accessLog]

[entryPoints.http]
address = ":80"

[frontends.dummy]
backend = "dummy"
entrypoints = ["http"]
[frontends.dummy.routes.all]
rule = "PathPrefix:/"

[backends.dummy.servers.server1]
url = "http://server1:80"
```

I can access server1 with no problem from localhost:8081 and `http://server1` from inside the `load-balancer` container. But `localhost:8080` keeps returning 404

The debug log

```
load-balancer_1  | time="2017-12-15T12:56:09Z" level=info msg="Using TOML configuration file /etc/traefik/traefik.toml"
load-balancer_1  | time="2017-12-15T12:56:09Z" level=info msg="Traefik version v1.5.0-rc2 built on 2017-12-06_03:07:42PM"
load-balancer_1  | time="2017-12-15T12:56:09Z" level=info msg="
load-balancer_1  | Stats collection is disabled.
load-balancer_1  | Help us improve Traefik by turning this feature on :)
load-balancer_1  | More details on: https://docs.traefik.io/basic/#collected-data
load-balancer_1  | "
load-balancer_1  | time="2017-12-15T12:56:09Z" level=debug msg="Global configuration loaded {"LifeCycle":{"RequestAcceptGraceTimeout":0,"GraceTimeOut":0},"GraceTimeOut":0,"Debug":true,"CheckNewVersion":true,"SendAnonymousUsage":false,"AccessLogsFile":"","AccessLog":{"format":"common"},"TraefikLogsFile":"","TraefikLog":null,"LogLevel":"DEBUG","EntryPoints":{"http":{"Network":"","Address":":80","TLS":null,"Redirect":null,"Auth":null,"WhitelistSourceRange":null,"Compress":false,"ProxyProtocol":null,"ForwardedHeaders":{"Insecure":true,"TrustedIPs":null}}},"Cluster":null,"Constraints":[],"ACME":null,"DefaultEntryPoints":["http"],"ProvidersThrottleDuration":2000000000,"MaxIdleConnsPerHost":200,"IdleTimeout":0,"InsecureSkipVerify":false,"RootCAs":null,"Retry":null,"HealthCheck":{"Interval":30000000000},"RespondingTimeouts":null,"ForwardingTimeouts":null,"Web":null,"Docker":null,"File":null,"Marathon":null,"Consul":null,"ConsulCatalog":null,"Etcd":null,"Zookeeper":null,"Boltdb":null,"Kubernetes":null,"Mesos":null,"Eureka":null,"ECS":null,"Rancher":null,"DynamoDB":null,"ServiceFabric":null,"Rest":null,"API":null,"Metrics":null,"Ping":null}"
load-balancer_1  | time="2017-12-15T12:56:09Z" level=info msg="Preparing server http &{Network: Address::80 TLS:<nil> Redirect:<nil> Auth:<nil> WhitelistSourceRange:[] Compress:false ProxyProtocol:<nil> ForwardedHeaders:0xc42060ea60} with readTimeout=0s writeTimeout=0s idleTimeout=3m0s"
load-balancer_1  | time="2017-12-15T12:56:09Z" level=info msg="Starting server on :80"
load-balancer_1  | 172.21.0.1 - - [15/Dec/2017:12:56:17 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" - - - "curl/7.54.0" 1 - - 0ms
```

The last access log is from the command

```
curl localhost:8080
```

and it returned

```
404 page not found
```

I don't want to use the docker backend, just want to let traefik do the conventional round-robin from the container. I wonder if it's possible?

Answer (score 1):

okay, after joining slack, Machael Matul pointed out you will need 
[file] declared somewhere after entry points

```
[file]
```

and for backend to work, it has to be before routes declaration on frontend.
example:

```
[frontends]
  [frontends.frontend1]
  backend = "buffalo"
    [frontends.frontend1.routes.web]
    rule = "Host:xyz.com"
  entrypoints = ["http","https"]
```

## example of complete:

```
debug = true
logLevel = "DEBUG"
defaultEntryPoints = ["https","http"]

[accessLog]

[web]
address = ":8080"
  [web.auth.basic]
  users = ["admin:md5hashedpassword"]

[acme]
  email = "info@xyz.com"
  storage = "/acme.json"
  entryPoint = "https"
  OnHostRule = true
  [acme.httpChallenge]
    entryPoint = "http"

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"

  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
  [entryPoints.https.tls]

[file]
watch = true

[backends]
  [backends.buffalo]
    [backends.buffalo.loadbalancer.stickiness]
    [backends.buffalo.servers.server1]
    url = "http://node1:3000"

    [backends.buffalo.servers.server2]
    url = "http://node2:3000"

  [backends.backendNginx]
    [backends.backendNginx.loadbalancer.stickiness]
    [backends.backendNginx.servers.server1]
    url = "http://nginx1:8080"

    [backends.backendNginx.servers.server2]
    url = "http://nginx2:8080"

  [backends.ai6forum]
    [backends.ai6forum.loadbalancer.stickiness]
    [backends.ai6forum.servers.server1]
    url = "http://10.140.0.9:80"

[frontends]
  [frontends.frontend1]
  backend = "buffalo"
    [frontends.frontend1.routes.web]
    rule = "Host:xyz.com"
  entrypoints = ["http","https"]
  passHostHeader = true
  passTLSCert = true
  priority = 10

  [frontends.nginx]
  backend = "backendNginx"
    [frontends.nginx.routes.web]
```